# Mongodb and Twitter array

Tags: php, mongodb

Code :

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('twitter');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'status');  
$cursor = $collection->find();  
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
  echo $document['statuses'][0]['text'];
}
```

Array :

```
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
    (
        [$id] => 123
    )

    [statuses] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
            [text] => Tweet no 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
            [text] => Tweet no 2
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
            [text] => Tweet no 3
            )
    )
)
```

The output is : Tweet no 1.

How do I get the whole 'text' array? It should return 'Tweet no 1, Tweet no 2, Tweet no 3' instead.

I've tried `echo $document['statuses']['text']` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your query is returning a collection, so you are iterating it correctly. The issue is it is a collection with only a single document and you are printing only the first status in that document:

```
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    // here $document = {_id: 123, statuses:[{text:'Tweet no 1'},{text:'Tweet no 2'},{text:'Tweet no 3'}]}
    // here you are only printing the first status       
    echo $document['statuses'][0]['text'];
}
```

Your document has an array of statuses, so you want to loop through that array:

```
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    foreach($document["status"] as $status) {
        echo $status['text'];
    }
}
```